# .NET Mutex causes starvation of the GUI Thread in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, mutex

The WinForm application has 20 threads running in the background, each one waits on the mutex.  When signaled, it does "a job" as in Thread.Sleep for around 100ms and releases it. Then waits 1 second, and does the job again.

```
private Mutex locker;

private void NewThread()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadLoopMutex);
    thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
    thread.Name = threadCounter++.ToString("D2");
    thread.Start();
}

private void ThreadLoopMutex()
{
    PrintLog("was created");
    while (true)
    {
        PrintLog("Lock1");
        locker.WaitOne();

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        PrintLog("UnLock1");
        locker.ReleaseMutex();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        PrintLog("Lock2");
        locker.WaitOne();

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        PrintLog("UnLock2");
        locker.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    locker = new Mutex();
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "GUI";
    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        NewThread();
    }
}
```

When the GUI Thread tries to wait on the same mutex, it never signals. It will wait on the Mutex for a long time while the other threads are playing with it smoothly.
When I set the 20 threads' job time to 30ms instead of 100ms, then the GUI Thread enters the mutex freely.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintLog("Lock");
    locker.WaitOne();

    Thread.Sleep(500);

    PrintLog("UnLock");
    locker.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: May be because putting UI in a background thread is not recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438988/3254405

Comment: Nothing very "freely" about it, the worker threads will just pile up on the WaitOne call since only one of them can acquire it.  Since there are 20 of them, and each thread only releases the mutex for 1000 msec, there is always a thread around that owns the mutex.  A delay in the UI thread of 4 seconds is expected.  You'll need either fewer threads or reduce the mutex ownership time.  And never block the UI thread, classes like Task and BackgroundWorker help you avoid that.

Comment: "for a long time" - how long?

Comment: Can be up to even 30 seconds

Comment: Given the UI thread is already waiting for the mutex, even then I would assume that after all the 20 threads were done, the UI thread will acquire it. But in reality the 20 threads take it over and over again without letting the UI thread in. It acquires the lock after half a minute. But if I make them hold the lock for shorter time, say 30ms, then the UI thread acquires the mutex without a noticeable delay at all.

Comment: I have a feeling that it might be related to how locking in UI thread works. UI thread, being STA, is not allowed to block. So when you do things like `WaitOne` in UI thread - framework uses different approach (compared to blocking in non-UI thread) and partially pumps a message loop from time to time. I tested your code in WPF application and can confirm `WaitOne` almost deadlocks in UI thread with your code, taking more than a minute. However, I don't know how exactly that "wait and pump" mechanism works, and can it be related or not (though I guess @HansPassant does).